# ASP DSN-Less Connection Issues

Tags: asp-classic, connection, dsn

Sorry if this isn't the appropriate place to put this question, but I'm new to the forums.

My issue relates to ASP and a DSN-less connection. I have a website, which was built quite a while ago using DSN connections to an Access database, which ran on a 2003 server. I have to replicate this site, but our servers (hosted through Fasthosts) are now 2008 servers, and don't support ODBC.

I have set up DSN-less connections, but I'm still not getting it right obviously as I keep getting Object required: 'object' on each page. I'm not really savvy with ASP, so if anybody can provide some answers that would be great!

The original code I had was this:

```
//Get the 5 newest news items
Dim objRec2, sql2, 
newstext sql2="SELECT TOP 5 news_date, news_text FROM news ORDER BY news_date DESC" 
set objRec2=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
objRec2.Open sql2,     "dsn=database"
```

Which I then changed to this:

```
//Get the 5 newest news items
set conob2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conob2.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" 
conob2.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & server.MapPath("database.mdb") Set rsuni2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")  
sql2="SELECT TOP 5 news_date, news_text FROM news ORDER BY news_date DESC" 
objRec2.Open sql, conob
```

I then get the error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'
Object required: 'objRec2'
index.asp, line 20
```

I'm running a 'WhileNot' statement to get the news_text and news_date like this:

```
<%While Not objRec2.EOF
            newstext = Replace(objRec2("news_text"), vbCrLf, "<br />")
            %>
            <p><span class="bold">Date: <%=objRec2("news_date")%></span><br />
            <%=newstext%></p>
```

Can anybody help with this please???

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your change are you seem to be missing:

`set objRec2=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")`

which would cause the exact error you encounter (and which is unrelated to the connection).

Comment: Thanks, I now get the error:

    ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78'

    Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

    /index.asp, line 79

Which relates to the 'While not' line.

Comment: @user1607021 check the names : is it objRec2.Open sql2, conob2 ?